# Microsoft removed the "Sounds" context menu option on the speaker in the May 2019 update (1903)

Tags: audio, context-menu, windows-10-v1903

As we all know, the latest version of Windows 10, May 2019, has removed the "Sounds" option from the context menu on the Windows speaker.

Before this update, the "Sounds" option looked like in the following image from last year.

[image]

What steps should I follow to return that option, as seen in the previous image?

Answer (score 1):

Although Microsoft removed the "Sounds" option from the context-menu of the Sound
icon, it can still be accessed in other ways.

- This is found in *Settings > System > Sound*.
  Click it to open the Control panel sound settings.
- In *Control Panel > Hardware and Sounds > Sounds*, you will find the old
  "Sound" window with Recording, Playback, Sounds, and Communications tab.
- For easier access you may create a Desktop shortcut to Sounds in the
  above Control Panel Sounds, by right-click on "Sound" and selecting Create Shortcut.
  This will create a shortcut on the desktop that you can use to open the
  Sound window.
  The equivalent command-line is:

  ```
  C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL Mmsys.cpl,,2
  ```
- I did find one way of modifying slightly the Volume menu by a registry edit
  that partly returns the old menu
  ([source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7948-use-old-new-volume-control-ui-windows-10-a.html)).
  This is undocumented and may be dependent on the installed sound driver.

  - Start `regedit`
  - Navigate to the key
    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\MTCUVC`
  - Create a DWORD (32-bit) value named `EnableMtcUvc`
  - Leave it at its default value `0` for the old menu, `1` for the new
  - Reboot

  This is the menu I got after this modification, where the "Advanced"
  option calls up the Sound applet:

  [image]
- Changing the Graphics driver might influence whether Sounds is displayed
  originally or with the above registry modification.

Answer (score 0):

There's no officially supported way to return the "Sounds" option to the speaker icon's right-click context menu.

The good news is that this inconvenience only adds one additional mouse click—you just need to know where to look!

You can quickly access the sound control panel just using your mouse, as follows:

1. Right click on the speaker icon
2. Select `Open Sound settings`

[image]

3. Scroll down, then select `Sound Control Panel`

[image]

In just three mouse clicks, you're there!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** I can only confirm this solution works for Realtek sound cards.

**1.** Disable Windows update drivers.

**2.** Install the original drivers of your Realtek card provided by the 
    manufacturer.

**3.** Restart

**4.** Now, the "Open Sound settings" option will lead us directly to "Sounds" (not Windows Sound settings).

Answer (score 0):

No way. Very disappointed with MS pushing of Metro. Use `mmsys.cpl` as a rescue.

Answer (score -1):

You can access that now if you type "Change system sounds" into search.

I'd really want to know what was the point of removing that little feature? I actually used that every day to switch between my speakers and headphones, since it wont switch without disabling the DFX Audio Enhancer first.